# Does Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 include library for MS unit testing?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

After I installed the SDK on our new Windows 7 build machine, I got errors from our unit test project:

```
DsHelperTest.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
SKMTest.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
UserTest.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
DsHelperTest.cs(30,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
DsHelperTest.cs(42,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
DsHelperTest.cs(60,40): error CS0118: 'TestSystemSoftware.DsHelperTest.TestContext' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
SKMTest.cs(23,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

any idea? needs to install another library package? we don't plan to have visual studio 2008 installed on that build machine.

thanks,

Comment: Unit testing is a feature of Visual Studio.  You will have to deploy it to your build server.  Copying the assemblies is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

The Unit testing assemblies are **not** included in the Windows SDK.  They are specific to Visual Studio.  In order to run your tests you should setup a [Controller with a Test Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182634(v=VS.90).aspx) on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft.VisualStudio namespace is part of the Visual Studio SDK, not the Windows SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: You should be able to deploy the necessary assembly from the SDK without installing the whole SDK.  That may be why it works on the XP machine.